# Find the first parameter of specific method calls with regex

Tags: regex

I have a some methods in a text file starting with

```
@Include("myparameter1", data);
bla1("myparameter2", data);
@Include("myparameter3", data);
```

That is my regex:

```
@"\((.*?)\)
```

It finds myparameter1, 2 and 3.

I only want to get literally myparameter1 and 3 without the quotes **myparameter1** and **myparameter3**

I also tried to prepend Include before the regex but it has no effect.

if regex is too hard for getting the myparameter1 it would even be ok if only the Include stuff would work because I could split the result at the "," and then trim the quotes...

Comment: All words which you want to extract contains same key? myparameter??

Comment: no haha do NOT take myparameter literally!

Comment: Which programming language are you using? And do you know how to use a *positive lookbehind*?

Comment: C#, no not yet. Does it help me?

Comment: Yes, `Regex.Match(text, @"\(""(.*?)""")?.Groups[1].Value`. Looks like `)` is not the right-hand boundary, it is just `"`. Can there be escaped quotes? Like `@Include("my\"para\"meter1", data);`?

Comment: HelloWorld, does that work?

Comment: no check an online regex tool nothing matched

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no escaped double-quotes within the double-quotes, you could match the required substring using `([^"]+)`, which means match and capture one or more characters that are not double-quotes.

C# string:

```
"@Include\(\"([^\"]*)\""
```

C# verbatim string :

```
@"@Include\(""([^""]*)"""
```

The required result is in `Groups[1]`, for example:

```
foreach (Match match in matches) {
  Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```